# Seeking Pseudo-code for Calculating the Smith and Schwartz Set

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, voting

I've read Wikipedia on the [Smith Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_set), [Schwartz Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_set), [Kosaraju's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm), [Tarjan's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm), and the [path-based strongly component algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-based_strong_component_algorithm); however, my experience with such algorithms is…lacking.  Wikipedia also says you can use a *version* of Kosaraju's algorithm to generate the Schwartz set—and that these algorithms can calculate the Smith set.

Wikpedia also has some pseudo-code for Tarjan's algorithm, but not the others; and it's not specific to this relatively-sensitive application.  I'm also not 100% certain which is the simplest to implement—which has the feature of least likelihood of errors in implementation.

I'd like some more-direct pseudocode to cover computing the Smith and Schwartz set from one of these algorithms, given a set of ranked ballots.  I find it easier to grasp concepts when I have a practical process I can walk.  I'll turn it into actual code myself.

Consider the following data structure:

```
Type Ballot {
  Array Votes[] {
    Candidate Candidate; // We do this in C#
    int Rank;
  }
}
```

For a collection of Ballots, each individual Ballot will contain an array Votes such as the following:

```
Ballot b.Votes[] =
  [ Vote(Alex.ID, 1),
    Vote(Chris.ID, 3),
    Vote(Sam.ID, 2) ];
```

This corresponds to a voter casting `Alex>Sam>Chris`, and there may be further candidates who are all equally less-preferred than Chris.

I assume the first step would be to tally the individual votes and graph the victory.  For example:  if 100 voters rank Alex above Sam (Alex = 1, Sam >= 2) and 50 voters rank Sam above Alex, Alex defeats Sam.  Thus I guess there'd be a data structure as such:

```
Type GraphNode {
  Candidate Candidate;
  GraphNode Array Defeats[];
  GraphNode Array Ties[];
  GraphNode Array DefeatedBy[];
}
```

Whereby a GraphNode for Alex would have an element in `Defeats[]` pointing to a GraphNode for Sam, and vice versa.

Given these GraphNodes, what do I do with it to identify the Smith and Schwartz sets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How efficient does this have to be? The Wikipedia articles also list the Floyd-Warshall algorithm that would be slower but much, much easier to implement.

Comment: If it's the same time complexity it's fine.  Most likely the graph's maximum size will only ever be 9, and so the upper bound for repeatedly re-calculating either set would be 7 runs.  Most likely any of these algorithms is fine, even the O(n^3) one.

Comment: With such a small graph you could even try all the subsets, there are only 2^9 = 512 possibilities. Still the O(n^3) Floyd-Warshall approach might even be easier.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how Floyd-Warshall applies. It identifies shortest path, but I'm looking at strongly-connected components. If A defeats B, B defeats C, C defeats A, and each of {A,B,C} defeats all of {D,E,F,G}, then the Smith Set is {A,B,C}.  I *believe* if C only *ties* with A, the Smith Set is {A,B,C} and the Schwartz Set is {A}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess python is close enough to pseudocode.

Let's say we have `n` candidates numbered from `0` to `n - 1`.

First you can compute a matrix `beats[i][j]` equal to `True` if candidate `i` beats candidate `j` and `False` otherwise.

Now compute the transitive closure of the matrix using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm:

```py
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            beats[i][j] = beats[i][j] or (beats[i][k] and beats[k][j])
```

After that the matrix has a slightly different meaning: `beats[i][j]` means there is a "beating path" `i -> c1 -> c2 -> ... -> j` such that `i` beats `c1`, `c1` beats `c2` and so on up to `j`.

The Schwartz components are the ones in which all pairs `i`, `j` have beating paths running both ways, and there's no other candidate that beats any of them (see the Wikipedia section on properties mentioning a *top cycle*).

Basically for each candidate `i` try building a component around it, like this:

```py
schwartz_components = []

for i in range(n):
    schwartz_component = {i}
    is_schwartz = True
    for j in range(n):
        if beats[j][i]:
            if beats[i][j]:
                schwartz_component.add(j)
            else:
                is_schwartz = False
    if is_schwartz:
         schwartz_components.append(schwartz_component)

schwartz_set = set.union(*schwartz_components)
print(schwartz_set)
```

For the Smith set it would be a bit different, you'd need to start with `cannot_beat[i][j] = not beats[i][j]`, use Floyd-Warshall on that and then build the set around each `i` by adding all the candidates with a path to it through the `cannot_beat` relation.

I guess it would go something like this (after the Floyd-Warshall step):

```py
smith_candidates = []

for i in range(n):
    smith_candidate = {i}
    for j in range(n):
        if cannot_beat[i][j]:
            smith_candidate.add(j)
    smith_candidates.append(smith_candidate)

# Take the smallest candidate
smith_set = min(smith_candidates, key=len)
```

There's likely a bug somewhere, but that's the idea, roughly.

Comment: Aha! That helps.  So, if I'm reading this right, the first iteration of k only finds things that immediately defeat one another (if A beats B beats C, we don't know that A beats C); but for (n) nodes, it re-walks the graph (n) times, and on pass (k) we've identified all beatpaths (k) long.  Yes, ok, this will work, and that's dead-simple.  Thanks!